# How to add an image to Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, server, windows, ssh

With Ubuntu Server being a completely text only OS, how do you add an image file? I have a webpage set up and would like to add an image or two. Open SSH is running on the server and connected to my laptop running Windows 7 (over PuTTY). Is there a way to somehow "drag-and-drop" an image file to the server from my laptop over Open SSH?

Thanks in advance,
Chandler

Yes, I may be a n00b but I am 13, and completely new to Linux and HTML in general. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using a program named WinSCP. It's a simple drag and drop utility that is free to use.

It is available [here](http://winscp.net).

Make sure you select the SFTP method.

Comment: Thank you! But that program gives me an error code in the SFTP session. 

"Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission denied
Request code: 13"

How can I get around this? I logged in with my username and password.

Comment: Okay, this is a bit more complicated. It sounds like you're trying to modify an area where you don't have permissions for. To fix this, try SFTPing it into a directory you do have permissions for (usually /home/<your login>) and then in PuTTY use the command: "sudo mv <where you saved it> <where you want to put it>"

Comment: Works perfectly. Any idea why that happens or how I could get permissions? This will get annoying in a hurry.

Comment: Not without introducing security issues. You could add a password for your root account but that's dangerous. Also, you could use the command chown, but that could break something.

Comment: Why would chown break something? I read a bit about it and it seems that it just changes the user of a directory....

Comment: If you chown a normally root only directory and remove root access, some services may not be able to write to there anymore.

Comment: I have found a workaround. Just open a PuTTY (or whatever terminal software you use) and type 'sudo -s' this will give you root access on your IP address (on whatever device you are using, ie. your laptop) for this session, therefore allowing you to move whatever files you would like wherever you would like them.